# How can I install Ubuntu 64 bits from 32 bits alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, usb, 64-bit, windows-10, reinstall

I have a notebook that came with Windows 10 installed and I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot, but I made the mistake of installing Ubuntu 32bits instead of the 64 bits version. Now Windows 10 will not start, apparently because I needed the 64 bits version of Ubuntu.

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with a boot-able pen drive but I don't know how to make the system boot from the USB, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If system came with Windows 10 it is UEFI.  If you installed Ubuntu 32 bit, that is BIOS boot only, so you should still be able to boot Windows by going into UEFI and select UEFI boot and Windows boot. You need 64 bit version of Ubuntu but must boot in UEFI boot mode, not BIOS.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Thanks Videonauth it worked really well and the resources you gave were really helpfull =)

Answer (score 0):

Your windows did not boot maybe because grub is missing. Try this in ubuntu and type this in terminal. Then restart your computer. You should be able to see the grub menu to choose between ubuntu and windows.

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you want to create a bootable usb installer, you can use Startup Disk Creator, an app already installed in Ubuntu.